# AngularJS Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am creating a single functionality : On a click of a button using AngularJS, i make an ajax call to some JSON data from the server.

Without the button functionality the following code is working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
function customersController($scope,$http) {
 $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
  .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i add a button click functionality the data doesnt get displayed on click of that button

```html
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">
    <button ng-click="getData()">Get Data</button> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
    function customersController($scope, $http) {
     $scope.getData()=   $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
         .success(function (response) { $scope.names = response; });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please Help!

Comment: `$scope.getData()=   $http.get(...)`. This is not valid javascript code.

Comment: thanks for your reply!
However tried your code too,not getting any data from the click of the button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two little errors here.

You can't assign something to the return value of a function. Look at what you're doing on this line: `$scope.getData()= $http......`. This is telling JS to **run** `$scope.getData` as a function, but you can't use an equal sign right afterwards to assign something to that return value. `$scope.getData` is also likely undefined, which is just going to be a script error.

The second thing you're doing wrong is that the code you wrote, assuming you fixed #1 and made it `$scope.getData = $http....` instead, is that you're immediately running that `$http.get` code, and then assigning the return to `$scope.getData`. What you really want to do is create a reusable function. You do this as follows:

```
$scope.getData = function () {
    // function instructions
}
```

Fix those two problems, and you should be golden.